# What does bbox refer to in this script?

Tags: python, pdf, pdfrw

I am new to Python and am trying to grasp existing scripts. This example is given from pdfrw as follows: http://code.google.com/p/pdfrw/wiki/ExampleTools

"A printer with a fancy printer and/or a full-up copy of Acrobat can easily turn your small PDF into a little booklet (for example, print 4 letter-sized pages on a single 11" x 17").

But that assumes several things, including that the personnel know how to operate the hardware and software. booklet.py lets you turn your PDF into a preformatted booklet, to give them fewer chances to mess it up:"

As best I can tell the steps are:

- the function starts looping through the pages
- a variable "shift_right" is declared that does ??? (I think it is for the metadata?)
- a variable "stuff" is declared that is useful only for metadata (I think)
- x is incremented by the third index of the BBox list (what is this list, when was it established?)
- y is assigned to the larger value between y and the third index of the Bbox list (again, what does this list refer to?)

I think my core confusion is regarding those two lines with BBox, and how they interact to create a 11x17 booklet PDF. Thank you for anyone who can clear this up.

```
    import sys
    import os

    import find_pdfrw
    from pdfrw import PdfReader, PdfWriter, PdfDict, PdfArray, PdfName, IndirectPdfDict
    from pdfrw.buildxobj import pagexobj
def fixpage(*pages):
    pages = [pagexobj(x) for x in pages]

    class PageStuff(tuple):
        pass

    x = y = 0
    for i, page in enumerate(pages):
        index = '/P%s' % i
        shift_right = x and '1 0 0 1 %s 0 cm ' % x or ''
        stuff = PageStuff((index, page))
        stuff.stream = 'q %s%s Do Q\n' % (shift_right, index)
        x += page.BBox[2]
        y = max(y, page.BBox[3])
        pages[i] = stuff

    # Multiple copies of first page used as a placeholder to
    # get blank page on back.
    for p1, p2 in zip(pages, pages[1:]):
        if p1[1] is p2[1]:
            pages.remove(p1)

    return IndirectPdfDict(
        Type = PdfName.Page,
        Contents = PdfDict(stream=''.join(page.stream for page in pages)),
        MediaBox = PdfArray([0, 0, x, y]),
        Resources = PdfDict(
            XObject = PdfDict(pages),
        ),
    )

inpfn, = sys.argv[1:]
outfn = 'booklet.' + os.path.basename(inpfn)
pages = PdfReader(inpfn).pages

# Use page1 as a marker to print a blank at the end
if len(pages) & 1:
    pages.append(pages[0])

bigpages = []
while len(pages) > 2:
    bigpages.append(fixpage(pages.pop(), pages.pop(0)))
    bigpages.append(fixpage(pages.pop(0), pages.pop()))

bigpages += pages

PdfWriter().addpages(bigpages).write(outfn)
```

Answer (score 4):

Bbox is typically shorthand for "bounding box": in this case, the rectangle defining the dimensions of your page.  In this case, it looks like it is an array of 4 numbers, the first two of which are the top-left corner of the page at (0,0), the third is the x-coordingate of the right side of the page (which, because the left side is at 0, is also the width), and the fourth is the bottom/height of the page.